# Rails: Login with remembering tests fail one after the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

This is part of the [railstutorial.org](https://railstutorial.org) for rails 7.I'm testing the correct working of the login with remembering

```
require 'test_helper'

class SessionsHelperTest < ActionView::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = users(:tony)
    remember(@user)
  end
  
  test 'current user returns right user when session is nil' do
    assert_equal @user,current_user
    assert is_logged_in?
  end

  test 'current user returns nil when remember digest is wrong' do
    @user.update_attribute(:remember_digest,User.digest(User.new_token))
    assert_nil current_user
  end
end
```

they refers to this helper

```
  def current_user
    if (user_id = session[:user_id])
      @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: user_id)
    elsif (user_id = cookies.encrypted[:user_id])
      
      user = User.find_by(id: user_id)
      if user && user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])
        log_in(user)
        @current_user = user
      end
    end
  end
```

the first test fails

```
 FAIL SessionsHelperTest#test_current_user_returns_right_user_when_session_is_nil (0.10s)
        --- expected
        +++ actual
        @@ -1 +1 @@
        -#<User id: 339078012, name: "tony fusco", email: "tony@example.com", created_at: "2022-10-04 07:33:09.980286000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-10-04 07:33:09.980286000 +0000", password_digest: [FILTERED], remember_digest: nil>
        +nil
        test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:10:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>'
```

and if i comment out part of a line 
`if user #&& user.authenticated?(cookies[:remember_token])`

the second test fails

```
FAIL SessionsHelperTest#test_current_user_returns_nil_when_remember_digest_is_wrong (2.29s)
        Expected #<User id: 339078012, name: "tony fusco", email: "tony@example.com", created_at: "2022-10-04 08:42:46.512404000 +0000", updated_at: "2022-10-04 08:42:48.782076000 +0000", password_digest: [FILTERED], remember_digest: "$2a$04$Haqx77Y7NRV/fCcirQiEU.tZnuqqXGIxD0n81FKTy84..."> to be nil.
        test/helpers/sessions_helper_test.rb:16:in `block in <class:SessionsHelperTest>'
```

p.s I'm reviewing the other questions about this argument,since they are all different I'm posting this, yet this topic is full of issues

Comment: this might not be the whole issue, but are you sure that this ```if (user_id = session[:user_id])```works? shouldnt this be **==** ?

Comment: no in the book it says `user_id` is a reference. It admits this is quite confusing but it's a way to save lines through refactoring, it is also written like this in the `elsif (user_id = cookies.encrypted[:user_id])`

Comment: ah yes, it does work, but seems like my linter doesnt like it at all.

Comment: I tested the code without refactoring: same failure results

Comment: well it seems that **user_id** is nil, so its likely that **session[:user_id]** and **cookies[:remember_token]** are nil or not valid ids?

Comment: as a super newbie I understood that the first test expects a value in `remember_digest` and instead get `nil`,the second test expects to get `nil` at `remember_digest` but obtain a value